# Show list of global functions with their brief

Tags: doxygen

I want to have a list of global functions with their corresponding brief, like for the Class List page.
How do I do this?

For example, in the "Namespace Members" page, how to show the briefs next to the function name and namespace?
Or in the "File/File Members/Functions" page, how to show the briefs next to the function name and the file name?